# how to find mid values of plot coordinates and segment the area into smaller rectangles?

Tags: sql, r

I have the data set 'datatoread' and following code as below, populates the dataframe 'MyData'.

```
datatoread <- "X Y
29 21
18 23
28 24
16 26
3 27
18 29
2 33
3 37
26 39
2 42
25 47
9 54
13 57
17 58
29 60
5 63
23 66
4 69
3 72
17 73
7 73
12 72
8 69
20 66
12 63
8 60
28 58
3 57
18 54
11 47
21 42
8 39
1 37
16 29
3 27
17 22
3 19
6 17
19 14
18 10"

MyData <- read.table(textConnection(datatoread), header = TRUE)
closeAllConnections()

MyData
```

What I want to do is:

1. Plot the data, find the mid value on X-axis and draw a vertical line from that X-value until Y-value (the corresponding Y coordinate to that mid-X).

   2. Segment the left half to the mid-X into equal distance (as shown in the picture below) and tabulate the segments in a way that results, say,

Result (please note these are only indicative for coordinates of segments, actual might differ)

```
 Seg  X1 Y1  X2 Y2
 seg1 18 23  29 21 
 seg2 29 21  28 24
  .   .  .    .  .
```

[image]

For first part of it, I tried in SAS as:

```
data Trapezoidal;
set x_y end=last;
retain integral;
lag_x=lag(x); lag_y = lag(y);
if _N_ eq 1 then integral = 0;
else integral = integral + (x - lag_x) * (y + lag_y) / 2;
run;
```

What could be equivalent code in R or SQL?

Alternatively, assume this data:

```
x <- seq(-12,12,by=1)
y <- dnorm(x,mean=2.5,sd=5)
plot(x,y, type = "l")
z <- cbind(x,y)
plot(z, type = "l")
```

You can work on 'z' dataframe as well.

Comment: The code to get the data frame you want could be something like this: `library(dplyr); datatoread <- datatoread %>%
  mutate(X1 = lead(X2), Y1 = lead(Y2)) %>%
  select(X1, Y1, X2, Y2)`. Not sure if I understand the graph.

Comment: Please `dput()` your data. And I don't understand your plot. Why is the x-axis not sorted? What are the x values? What are the corresponding y values?

Comment: @Christoph Y corresponding to X is in the table. we can sort X, if needed.

Comment: @NickCriswell Let's use Y for plotting and X can be anything from 0 to max_val . The idea here is to find X value where Y is max and then create smaller segments (just like smaller rectangles in Area Under the Curve Trapezoidal Method)

Comment: But if you sort x, the graph looks really different. It will have a different shape.

Comment: @Christoph I added an alternative dataset.

Comment: Please `dput(datatoread)` and I will try to make a suggestion.